# using regex to replace words not enclosed in <> signs

Tags: java, regex

I really need some help forming a regex pattern in java.

I am trying to replace all occurrences of a given word provided that it is not enclosed within a less-than or greater-than sign.  It should not replace it even if the less/greater-than signs are not directly next to the word.  Here is my most recent attempt:

```
    stringIn = stringIn.replaceAll("((?:<[^>]>[^<]*)+" + word + "(?:<[^>]>[^<]*)+)", "$1<" + newWord + ">$2");
```

But this does not seem to replace the word not in brackets.
Just to clarify I made up an example replacement:

```
    "foo word <word> <foo word foo>" should go to
    "foo <newWord> <word> <foo word foo>
```

PS Just saw  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700203/regex-replace-word-when-not-enclosed-in-brackets)  and it looks similar but I don't really understand it and cannot guaranty it as it refers to PHP not Java.

Comment: What do you think the `?` is for in your regex?

Comment: what are the acceptable and unacceptable inputs ?

Comment: to make the inner bracket non capturing @Dukeling

Comment: @SaadAttieh For that, use the syntax `(?:abc)`. `(?abc)` won't work.

Comment: @Sujith PS not sure exactly what you mean but basically it might have an input of <blablabla word blablabla>  word <word> and only the second "word" should be replaced as the first two are within less/greater than signs.

Comment: @Ryan Carlson cheers for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the regex

```
word(?=[^>]*(?:$|<))
```

The items contained in `{}` in the following explanation show what part of the regex is explained by the previous phrase: The regex looks for a word {`word`} [that is followed by {`(?=...)`}](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) [a sequence of zero or more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [characters {`[...]*`} that does not include the character `>` {`^>`}](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and is immediately followed by the [end of the string {`$`}](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) [or {`(?:...|...)`}](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) the character `<` {`<`}.

You can find a demonstration and another explanation here: http://regex101.com/r/tY5cT7

Implemented in Java, it would look like this:

```
stringIn = stringIn.replaceAll(word + "(?=[^>]*(?:$|<))", "<" + newWord + ">");
```

<sup>Note: this assumes that all `<...>` are balanced, i.e. for every `<` there is one and only one corresponding `>`, and for every `>` there is one and only one corresponding `<`.</sup>

Comment: Great Answer!  Thanks - could you possibly explain why this works?  just not sure as you are able to put the word to replace at the beginning of the regex.  Also what does the = sign do?

Comment: @SaadAttieh I edited my answer to include a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that should work for you:

```
String newWord = "-REPLACED-";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(<[^>]*>)|(\\bword\\b)" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( "foo word <word> <foo word foo> word" );
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.groupCount()>1 && m.group(2) != null)
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "<" + newWord + ">");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println( sb );
```

#### OUTPUT

```
foo <-REPLACED-> <word> <foo word foo> <-REPLACED->
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this :

```
String val="<blablabla word blablabla> word123 <word>";
String REGEX="(?<=>)[^<]+";
String replaceString="replace";
System.out.println(val.replaceAll(REGEX, replaceString));
```

**Output**

```
<blablabla word blablabla>replace<word>
```

**[Refer](http://regex101.com/r/oU4dW8)**

Comment: Try this on the input `word`.